# Nav width not changing with content

Tags: html, css, width, nav

I have a nav bar that displays fine when I have 5 navigation objects in it but when I add 3 more it drops below the main header why?

**5 Objects:**

[image]

**7 Objects:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="w960">
        <div id="logo">
            <h2>Text</h2>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="first active">
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">4 </a>
                </li>
                <li class="last">
                    <a href="#">5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of header -->
```

​

**CSS:**

```
#header{background:#2d2d2f;width:100%; height:120px;clear:both;font-family:Signika,Arial,sans-serif;}

.w960 { width:960px; margin:auto; }

nav{width:auto; float:right;line-height: 50px;}
nav ul li{font-size:14px; float:left;display: inline-block;padding: 0px 11px;text-transform:uppercase;}
nav ul li a{padding: 0px 10px; color:#ffb400; text-decoration:none;}
nav ul li a:hover, .active a{color:#fff}

#logo{width: 40%;float: left;height: 90px;}
#logo h2{line-height: 41px;color:#FFB400;font-size:28px;}
#logo h2 span{color:#FFB400;}
#logo p {margin-top: -25px;color:#b8bbbc;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two floating elements in the same line, if the sum of both width and they are bigger than the available space, they will break the line and place the second floating element below the previous: in your case nav below logo. Add borders to each of them and you will see that they are just too big.

One alternative is this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bs93k/

```
nav{width:auto; /*float:right;*/ overflow:auto; line-height: 50px;}
```

This will make nav to take the available space, however, I don't think its contents would behave as you like.

A second alternative is this: http://jsfiddle.net/PU7hV/

```
#header{display:table;}
.w960 {position:relative;}
nav{/*float:right;*/ position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
```

Note that i wrote what you have to add and commented what to delete, the rest, leave them as you already had.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to ask why the background of the header container does not appear behind the links, it's because of the floated `li`s.

You will need to add a `clearfix` class.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

And apply that class to your header:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
```

If you mean why do they break down a line at all, it's because of the fixed width on the `<div class="w960">` container.

```
.w960 { width:960px; margin:auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin,  I have tried extending the width but that changes the whole format of the header.  What would be the best way to CSS my nav?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have no dropdown submenu I'd recommend to use overflow: hidden.

```
nav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change the HTML (for example you don't have access to the script which outputs the HTML) adding clearfix, you could just change the CSS like that:

```
#header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2D2D2F;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    font-family: Signika,Arial,sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That just makes it bigger,  I want to be able to display it in a specific area like with 5 items

Comment: are you able to set `<li>` CSS as 20% for example for 5 items? 10% for 10 items and etc.?